# What happened to the title?

Tags: titles

I am using the `article` class. The article title is not displaying and I can't figure out why. This is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article} 
\usepackage{geometry} 
\geometry{a4paper}
\geometry{a4paper} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip} 

\title{Terms of Business}
\author{ABC Company}
\date

\begin{document}
123
\end{document}
```

Comment: you must use \maketitle to print it.

Comment: Also, it's `\date{somedate}`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer please make this an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Change `\date` for `\date{}`, or, delete `\date`, then it will produce a date of today.
2. Insert `\maketitle` after `\begin{document}`.

Comment: Who TF downvoted this correct answer, and why?

Comment: @Ingmar Posting people's prior comments as an answer is bad etiquette regardless of if you knew the answer, vote to close if the comments solved it (which they did in this case) or move on. Relax with the aggressiveness too, we are all allowed to disagree on things, I downvoted it so go ahead with the revenge downvoting if you desire, I have my instant-edit rights now so I am happy.

Comment: Perceived bad etiquette or not, in my book the downvote is literally for answers that are "not useful". YMMV.